# Forming an new javascript array by combining two columns of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to form a new array in javascript that consists of two 1 dimentional arrays (of the same length).

```
var A = [1,2,3];
var B = [20, 10, 30];
```

and I want to create C:

```
C = [[1,20],[2,10],[3,30]];
```

This seems like a fairly simple problem. I am wondering if there is a function I can use for this (to avoid loops). Perhaps something with [array.from](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) or map? I am having some trouble figuring out how that would work exactly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try following

```js
 var A = [1, 2, 3];
 var B = [20, 10, 30];

 var C = A.map(function(item, index) {
   return [item, B[index]]

 });

 console.log(C);
```

Answer (score 1):

For the same length array we can use map function - Nikhil's Answer

I am just providing more information if both array's are of different lengths.

```
 function mixArray(a, b) {
   if (a.length < b.length) {
     var j = Array(b.length-a.length).fill('');  
     a = a.concat(j);
   }

 return a.map(function(item, index) {
     var tempArr = [];
     if (item !== '') {
       tempArr.push(item);
     }
     if (b[index] !== undefined) {
       tempArr.push(b[index]);
     }
     return tempArr;
  });

}
```

Inputs

```
var a = [1, 2, 3, 7, 8, 9];
var b = [20, 10, 30, 5];
console.log(mixArray(a,b));  // [[1, 20], [2, 10], [3, 30], [7, 5], [8], [9]]

var a = [1, 2];
var b = [20, 10, 30, 5];
console.log(mixArray(a,b)); // [[1, 20], [2, 10], [30], [5]]
```

Hope this helps ! Thanks
Demo : https://jsbin.com/dusuna/edit?html,js,console